# Visual Studio 2015 / IIS Express and ApiController POST events

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Whenever I try to run my solution locally that contains a   POST(IHttpActionResult) event to an API, I get a message saying 'this controller does not support GET'...even though it's a POST event. However, if I publish the solution to my web server, it works fine. Is there a way to configure my local dev environment to support POST events?

The controller just contains one simple method:

```
    [Route("api/factories/add/{newLocation}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string newLocation)
    {
       ...do stuff...
        return Ok(stuff);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `HttpPost` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/factories/add/{newLocation}")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string newLocation)
{
   ...do stuff...
    return Ok(stuff);
}
```